# How to display images in Grid using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am uploading multiple images. I am selecting image one by one and displaying image for preview. But it is displaying in vertical format. I am trying to display it in Grid format. Kindly have a look.

```js
var abc=0;
$('#add_more').click(function() {
  $(this).before($("<div/>", {
    id: 'filediv'
  }).fadeIn('slow').append(
    $("<input/>", {
      name: 'file[]',
      type: 'file',
      id: 'file'
    }),
    $("<br/><br/>")
  ));
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
};

$('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

    var z = abc - 1;
    var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
    $(this).before("<div id='abcd" + abc + "' class='abcd'><img style='height:100px; width:100px;' id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    src = '<?=ASSET_BASE_URL?>scripts/script.js'
    $(this).hide();
    $("#abcd" + abc).append($("<img/>", {
      id: 'img',
      src: '/assets/x.png',
      alt: 'delete'
    }).click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
  Please upload your menu.
  <hr/>
  <div id="filediv" style="width:120px;height=120px;">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" id="file" />
  </div>
  <br/>

  <input type="button" id="add_more" class="btn" value="Add More Menu" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with the var àbc` and the imageISLoaded function

Comment: @mplungjan Did you update the snippet in 5 seconds?

Comment: @mplungjan dear, i just updated. I am using new function also ** imageIsLoaded**. it is working in locally.

Comment: I added `abc=0` now the script works

Comment: @mplungjan yes sir it is working in snippet. Now i am trying to display images in GRID format.

Comment: Just add `.abcd { float:left }`

Comment: @mplungjan WOW you are god of Jquery. Thanks +500

Comment: Haha - it was not jQuery, just CSS

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you soo much Sir.

Comment: Actually Flexbox is more interesting for you. See duplicate

Comment: ok sir. i will read it.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best possible solution, but it might get you on the right way:

```js
var abc=0;
$('#add_more').click(function() {
  $('#thumbs').append($("<div/>", {
    style: 'display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;',
  }).fadeIn('slow').append(
    $("<input/>", {
      name: 'file[]',
      type: 'file',
      id: 'file'
    }),
    $("<br/><br/>")
  ));
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
};

$('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

    var z = abc - 1;
    var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
    $(this).before("<div id='abcd" + abc + "' class='abcd'><img style='height:100px; width:100px;' id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    src = '<?=ASSET_BASE_URL?>scripts/script.js'
    $(this).hide();
    $("#abcd" + abc).append($("<img/>", {
      id: 'img',
      src: '/assets/x.png',
      alt: 'delete'
    }).click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
  Please upload your menu.
  <hr/>
  <div>
  <div id="thumbs">
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file" /></div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div>
  <input type="button" id="add_more" class="btn" value="Add More Menu" />
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```